# How We Maintain Tenant Data Isolation for Kafka in Spring cloud dataflow kafka binder?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

As you can imagine, our most valuable asset is our clients’ data, and as a SaaS company, it’s critical for us to avoid processing mixed-tenant data batches through our Kafka pipelines. So how we can create a Kafka binder as tenet specific while using spring cloud data flow.

Answer (score 0):

You can set permissions (acl, rbac) for kafka topics to prevent or allow reading/writing from different clients to different topics and authenticate to your kafka cluster.